# VS Code. Flutter. Проблема с форматированием кода

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter, dart

Я использую Visual Studio Code для написания приложений на Flutter и хочу отформатировать код при помощи сочетания клавиш `alt + shift + f`, но вместо того, чтобы результат получился такой:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: 
      Center(child: 
        Text(
          'Hello Flutter',
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          style:TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Код становится таким:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Center(
          child: Text(
    'Hello Flutter',
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    style:
        TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ))));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для такого форматирования Вам необходимо расставить запятые. Вида:

```dart
MaterialApp(home: 
  Center(child: 
    Text(
      'Hello Flutter',
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      style:TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
...
```